# GridPanel Store Not Loading

Tags: json, web-services, extjs, store, ext.net

I am trying to load a simple GridPanel with a Store created in code behind. I'm not sure what I'm missing but when I add the Store to the GridPanel it just says "Loading..." and never loads.

The GridPanel is defined as follows:

```
<ext:GridPanel ID="SearchSoftwareGrid" runat="server" MultiSelect="true" Height="224"
    Padding="1" Width="398">
    <ColumnModel>
        <Columns>
            <ext:Column ID="Column4" runat="server" Text="Publisher" Width="45" DataIndex="PUBLISHER"
                Flex="1" />
            <ext:Column ID="Column5" runat="server" Text="Product" Width="175" DataIndex="PRODUCT" />
            <ext:Column ID="Column6" runat="server" Text="Version" Width="50" DataIndex="PRODUCT_VERSION" />
            <ext:Column ID="Column7" runat="server" Text="Instance Count" Width="85" DataIndex="INSTANCE_COUNT" />
        </Columns>
    </ColumnModel>
    <View>
        <ext:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
            <Plugins>
                <ext:GridDragDrop ID="GridDragDrop2" runat="server" DragGroup="secondGridDDGroup"
                    DropGroup="firstGridDDGroup" />
            </Plugins>
            <Listeners>
                <Refresh Handler="#{SearchSoftwareGrid}.body.unmask(); #{btnSearchSoftware}.enable();"
                    Delay="1" />
            </Listeners>
        </ext:GridView>
    </View>
</ext:GridPanel>
```

This is the method I use to create the Store in code behind:

```
private Ext.Net.Store GetSoftwareStore(string search)
{
string proxyUrl = softwareUrl + search;

Ext.Net.Model softwareStoreModel = new Ext.Net.Model();
softwareStoreModel.Fields.Add(new Ext.Net.ModelField("PUBLISHER", ModelFieldType.String));
softwareStoreModel.Fields.Add(new Ext.Net.ModelField("PRODUCT", ModelFieldType.String));
softwareStoreModel.Fields.Add(new Ext.Net.ModelField("PRODUCT_VERSION", ModelFieldType.String));
softwareStoreModel.Fields.Add(new Ext.Net.ModelField("INSTANCE_COUNT", ModelFieldType.String)); 

Ext.Net.Store resultStore = new Ext.Net.Store()
{
    AutoLoad = true,
    Proxy =
    {
        new Ext.Net.AjaxProxy()
        {
            Json = true,
            ActionMethods = { Read = Ext.Net.HttpMethod.POST, Create = Ext.Net.HttpMethod.POST },
            Url = proxyUrl,
            Headers = {
                new Ext.Net.Parameter("Accept", "application/json"),
                new Ext.Net.Parameter("Content-Type", "application/json")
            },
            Reader = { new Ext.Net.JsonReader() { Root = "" } },
            Writer = { new Ext.Net.JsonWriter() { Root = "", Encode = true } }
        }
    }
};
resultStore.Model.Add(softwareStoreModel);        

return resultStore;
}
```

I try to add the Store like this, where `txtSearchsoftware` is entered by the user and is used to populate the `proxyUrl` above:

```
SearchSoftwareGrid.Store.Add(GetSoftwareStore(txtSearchsoftware.Text));
```

The proxyUrl is for a web service that returns some JSON. Example:

> http://[MachineName]/OperationalControlServices/Service1/data/ComponentMapping?Search=db2

I know the web service is fine because it returns correctly using Fiddler.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SearchSoftwareGrid.Store= GetSoftwareStore(txtSearchsoftware.Text);
```